# Updating progress bar (bootstrap) after each input completion and its validation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a problem where I need to fill in the form and automatically update the progress bar. The from can be switched, so the number of inputs may vary (it's not guaranteed to always be static a number of 6 or 7 inputs).

*The snippet below looks messy only because of bootstrap beautifications*

```js
const app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
signUpCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "uibDateParser"];
app.controller("signUpCtrl", signUpCtrl);


function signUpCtrl($scope, uibDateParser) {
  $scope.model = {};
  $scope.formType = "student";

  $scope.submitStudent = function() {
    console.log($scope.model);
  }

  $scope.submitTeacher = function() {
    console.log($scope.model);
  }

  $scope.changeForm = function(type) {
    $scope.formType = type;
  }

}
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="signUpCtrl">

    <div ng-switch="formType">
      <div ng-switch-when="student">
        <div class="form-group">
          <h3>Sign up as a student</h3>
          <form name="signupForm" ng-submit="submitStudent()">
            <div class="input-group" ng-class="{ 'has-success': signupForm.firstname.$valid && signupForm.firstname.$dirty, 'has-error': !model.name && signupForm.firstname.$dirty }">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></span>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="model.name" placeholder="First name">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group" ng-class="{ 'has-success': signupForm.lastname.$valid && signupForm.lastname.$dirty, 'has-error': !model.surname && signupForm.lastname.$dirty }">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></span>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="model.surname" placeholder="Last name">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group" ng-class="{ 'has-success': signupForm.username.$valid && signupForm.username.$dirty, 'has-error': !model.username && signupForm.username.$dirty }">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-fw"></i></span>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" ng-model="model.username" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group" ng-class="{ 'has-success': signupForm.dob.$valid, 'has-error': !model.dob && signupForm.dob.$dirty }">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i></span>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="dob" ng-model="model.dob" uib-datepicker-popup="{{'d!/M!/yyyy'}}" required placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group" ng-class="{ 'has-success': signupForm.email.$valid, 'has-error': signupForm.email.$invalid && signupForm.email.$dirty }">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
              <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" ng-model="model.email" required placeholder="Email address">
            </div>
            <div ng-class="{ 'has-success': signupForm.pass.$valid && signupForm.pass2.$valid && signupForm.pass.$dirty && signupForm.pass2.$dirty, 'has-warning': (model.password.length < 6 && model.password_confirm.length < 6) && signupForm.pass.$dirty && signupForm.pass2.$dirty, 'has-error': (model.password != model.password_confirm) && signupForm.pass.$dirty && signupForm.pass2.$dirty }">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="pass" ng-model="model.password" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt fa-fw"></i></span>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="pass2" ng-model="model.password_confirm" placeholder="Confirm password">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success  progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{count}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="7" ng-style="{'width': count*(100/7)+'%'}">
                <span ng-show="count && count<7">{{count}}/7</span>
                <span ng-show="count && count==7">Completed</span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-disabled="count != 7">Sign up</button>
          </form>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" ng-click="changeForm('teacher')">I am a teacher</button>
      </div>

      <div ng-switch-when="teacher">
        <div class="form-group">
          <h3>Sign up as a teacher</h3>
          <form name="signupForm" ng-submit="submitTeacher()">
            <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></span>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="model.name" placeholder="First name">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></span>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="model.surname" placeholder="Last name">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-fw"></i></span>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="model.username" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="model.email" placeholder="Email address">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
              <input class="form-control" type="password" ng-model="model.password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt fa-fw"></i></span>
              <input class="form-control" type="password" ng-model="model.password_confirm" placeholder="Confirm password">
            </div>

            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success  progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{count}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="6" ng-style="{'width': count*(100/6)+'%'}">
                <span ng-show="count && count<6">{{count}}/6</span>
                <span ng-show="count && count==6">Completed</span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-disabled="count != 6">Sign up</button>
          </form>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" ng-click="changeForm('student')">I am a student</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h3><small>This button updates progress manualy:</small></h3>
    <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="count = count + 1">Testing</button>

  </div>
</body>
```

There is a potential to use `$watch`, but I'm not sure if it's the best approach for my problem. I need it to know that there are 6/7/more inputs that can be switched, disabled, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain different progress bars for different forms.
You will get to know number of inputs for each form so calculate 100% by number of inputs there. After every input is filled and validated(email, phone number etc) you can raise the percentage filled amount and store it in scope variable.
Even if form is switched you can either continue with scope variable (fields filled) or make it to 0.

Comment: what function would raise the percentage if the input is filled in? `$watch`? `ng-change`? something else? will it affect anything if I switch the form?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning! Use ng-change.
will it affect anything if I switch the form? - No as per my thinking

Comment: seems all good, but how should I add 1 to my progress bar only from a specific input form? (with a minimum number of watchers) i.e. if I fill only two forms in any order it should be 2/7

Comment: If your question is about forms - If forms are 5, each form value will be 20% so once a form ng-submit is worked right! then u can raise the progress bar filled percentage to 20%, similarly for all forms so for first form completion your progress bar would be 1/5. 
Same if your question is for inputs in a single form.

Comment: No, I had individual `<input>`s in one form, that can be filled in any order. For now I have an object of all possible input results, so that if one of them is filled in, it will only increase the progress by for that input, where I then `.reduce()` that object to get the total number of filled in inputs

Comment: but I was hoping for an alternative solution